# jmeter unable to capture request from ERP application that uses own proxy

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, socks

I have been looking into testing an ERP application written in Java on top of Eclipse. The application comes with its own jre and so on. I don't have access to the source code but I do now from the developers and my own research that the application calls its backend hosted on Amazon cloud.

After setting up my jmeter proxy I noticed that it captures anything from chrome but not from my ERP application. The ERP application is able to just bypass any proxy settings I set.

The only interesting thing I noticed is that if I set my jmeter proxy as a SOCKS proxy in system settings (or just as SOCKS proxy for the VM running the ERP application) then entire application just crashes.

This leads me to believe that the application might be behind some kind of proxy itself which prevents jmeter from capturing the requests.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to complete 2 steps:

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). The easiest way is using [JMeter Templates feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature):

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Configure your application to use JMeter as a proxy. According to [Java Networking and Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) article you need to set the following System Properties:

   ```
   http.proxyHost=localhost
   http.proxyPort=8888
   ```

   and just in case your application is using HTTPS transport:

   ```
   https.proxyHost=localhost
   https.proxyPort=8888
   ```

   The properties can be set via -D command line argument like:

   ```
   java -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 ... your application
   ```

   or you can add them to your application startup script.

Comment: Already tried setting system properties for HTTP and HTTPS but they do nothing, the application continues to work but jmeter is not able to capture any requests. Only when I set socksProxyHost and socksProxyPort does the application actually crash with a network connection error.